# How to trace the intersection of an image with the boundaries of an irregular shaped image in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an image of mountain with small gutters and tunnels in it. I want to pass a small image through that tunnels. How to trace the intersection of that small image with the exact boundaries of large image in cocos2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a collision mask for this.

What this means is to create an exact copy of the image you are using for your terrain except make it only two colors: white and black.

[image: Example collision mask]

Make the areas that you want the player to be able to move through (not walls) white. Make the walls and anything you want the  player to collide with back. Next, just do some pixel collision detection. To do this, I would get the RGB (not RGBA because alpha doesn't matter) data. Loop through this data (or a section of it for better performance) and detect whether or not the player is on a black or white pixel.

Do whatever you need to accordingly.

If you need more help, feel free to ask.